# What's an alternative method to QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI to tell if a function from a delay-loaded DLL is available that will work in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, delay-load

I'm writing a C++ Windows desktop app that makes use of delay-loaded DLLs in order to support different versions of the DLL that has different functions available.

If I were targeting Windows 10 and later, I could use the function `QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI` to tell if a function is available. Unfortunately, I need to target Windows 7 as well and `QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI` isn't available there.

What's another method I can use to detect of a delay-loaded function is available that works in Windows 7?

edit: To be clear, I need to check if the function is available without trying to call it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/error-handling-and-notification?view=msvc-170

Comment: @HansPassant I've seen that document and it doesn't exactly make it clear how you would check to see if a specific function is available before calling it. I'm hoping someone can provide a better explanation or an example.

Comment: I don't understand what delay load has to do with using different versions of a DLL.

Comment: There isn't any point anymore in using /delayload if you want to do that, might as well use the standard LoadLibrary+GetProcAddress.  Whjch is why the article focuses on handling the exception you get when the export is missing.

Comment: @HansPassant I disagree, there's certainly a point. The DLL in question has hundreds of functions in it. I don't want to have to call GetProcAddress for each one. But there's a small handful of functions it may not have depending on its version, and using delay loaded DLLs is a very convenient way of still being able to automatically load it regardless of which version is available at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually calling the function, the only option you have in this case is to load the DLL into memory via `LoadLibrary/Ex()` and then use `GetProcAddress()` to get a pointer to the desired function.  If either fail, the function is not available. If both are successful, you will have a pointer with which you can call the function, if desired.

This is essentially all the delay-loading mechanism does internally (besides its notification hooks).

What you could do is wrap this logic into your own function, and then delay-load `QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI()` itself, using a [failure hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/error-handling-and-notification?view=msvc-170#failure-hooks) to let you know when `QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI()` is not available so you can map it to your custom function instead.  This way, the rest of your code can just call `QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI()` unconditionally on all Windows versions, and your custom function will be called on older versions.

Or, you can just do the same thing for other missing DLL functions.  Just write your own replacement functions that mimic the official functions, and/or return error codes that your code can look for, like `ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`, etc.